# Firebase Authencation

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth as login method in android mobile app. If there is an existing user in the app, I point him to the event. But when I delete or disable this user in firebase, the user can continue to use the app as it is currently registered in the app. What I want to do is, when I delete the user, the user should open the application and go to the login screen. I tried the onStateChange method, but it didn't work when the app was closed. I am waiting for your return. Have a nice day.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) or this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help.